# Configure SAML Single Sign-on in Azure with ITfoxtec SAML 2.0

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to implement SAML authentication in .Net Core 3.1. I'm using the sample project `TestWebAppCore` from this official [repo](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore).

I have the values below and I need to adapt the sample project considering Azure AD as an Identity Provider:

- `Login URL`
- `Azure AD Identifier`
- `Logout URL`
- I also have a `.xml` and a `.cer` file.

My questions are:

- `Login URL` is the configuration `SingleSignOnDestination`?
- `Logout URL` is the configuration `SingleLogoutDestination`?
- `Azure AD Identifier` is the configuration `IdPMetadata`?
- Can I remove the code that refers to `SigningCertificatePassword` (`.pfx` file) and add reference to my `.cer` file?
- Do I need to use the `xml` file? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  integrate with an Azure AD Enterprise Application I think you should use the Enterprise Applications metadata to configure (config parameter `IdPMetadata`) ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 in the .NET application.

- SingleSignOnDestination is the Azure AD Enterprise Application login endpoint.
- SingleLogoutDestination as I remember an Azure AD Enterprise Application do not support SAML 2.0 logout.
- AllowedIssuer is the Azure AD Enterprise Application issuer.
- SigningCertificate need to contain a certificate with both public and private key like a .pfx. A .cer only contain the public key.

Comment: Thanks, my customer let I use OpenId!