# Capable to keep logging-in on sample project in Azure with ITfoxtec SAML 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm validating AAD-SSO for TestWebApp(ASP.NET MVC) ITfoxtec / ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.
I confirmed login -> AAD sign-in -> Redirect to app but app still remains not logging-in.
I assigned "https://localhost:***/Metadata" as Redirect Uri.
I checked the other settings from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64450539/configure-saml-single-sign-on-in-azure-with-itfoxtec-saml-2-0).
However that means the app only makes a xml file.

Tell the procedure if there's anyone who succeeded logging-in on app?
Or do I have to build new logic?
e.g. of logic) receive session from AAD and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `https://localhost:***/Metadata` is the metadata URL. AAD needs to redirect back to the applications AssertionConsumerService endpoint.

You can have AAD reading the metadata or you can configure the AssertionConsumerService endpoint manually in AAD.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'll change redirect Url to AssertionConsumerService and change Saml2configuration to correct value.